# Cut edges in the UV Editor

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have an UVMap and I try to editing that. As we can see below there are couple of faces which are not placed very well.

[image]

So I would like to separate those faces in order to place them from here:

[image]

To here:

[image]

But I can't find the solution to cut edges to separate faces in the UV Editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1: In the UV/image Editor select the vertices/faces thet need to be moved and use the Keyboard shortcut key **Y** to separate them.

2: Move them to their new position.

3 To join them back to the UV's...... select each pair of vertices to be joined then open the **Weld/Align** menu with the **W** key and choose **Weld**.

Comment: So the Y shortcut is basically the (mesh) split function. Unfortunately it is not documented right now [Editing UVs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/layout_editing.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can give those two faces an exclusive material & texture slot, then UV unwrap them separately.  Move and scale them in the UV editor independently to take the part of the texture you're seeking, and also to match them up with their surrounds.

Comment: This sounds like absolute overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: When I read the ans above - I agree!  It's gone into my little black book.